# What is the correct pattern to the text?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a String as follows:

```
var str = "Visit {Inside String}";
```

I want to replace {Inside String} with 'mySchool'.

I tried doing something like below

```
var n = str.replace(/[{][^\s*][^\*}]/,'mySchool');
```

But this is not working as expected.

Any pointer?

Comment: I don't get what you tried to do with this `[^\s*]`.

Comment: Why do you wanna use regular expressions? You could simply replace the string with `str.replace('{Inside String}', 'mySchool')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
var n = str.replace(/\{[^}]*\}/,'mySchool');
```

Note that if you have more than one replacement to do you'll have to use the g flag :

```
var n = str.replace(/\{[^}]*\}/g,'mySchool');
```

Answer (score 4):

Then why not just replace it without creating a `RegExp` instance?

```
var n = str.replace("{Inside String}",'mySchool');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a better regex:

```
var n = str.replace(/\{.+?\}/, 'mySchool');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var n = str.replace(/[{][^}]*[^}]/g,'mySchool');
```

Your regexp `/[{][^\s*][^\*}]/` can be read as:

```
(A opening brace) + (not a space nor a star char) + (not a backslash, star or closing brace char)
```

which is not what you want.